# NSComboBox - how can I implement a delegate for 2 different comboBoxes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, combobox, nscombobox

I've implemented the NSComboBoxDelegate:

```
-(void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{

}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

}

- (void)comboBoxWillPopUp:(NSNotification *)notification{

}

- (void)comboBoxWillDismiss:(NSNotification *)notification{
}
```

but I have 2 comboBoxes - with 2 different functionalities. 
is there a way to know which comboBox is no on the run, and act accordingly?

or do I have to implement 2 different delegates outside? and if so - is there an easy way to transfer information back to my viewcontroller?

is there a way to get info about the sender of the **notification**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For text change (controlTextDidEndEditing, controlTextDidChange...), see the following example.

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
    if ([obj object] == combobox1) {

    }
    else if ([obj object] == combobox2) {

    }
}
```

As for selection change, you need to create IBAction connections for respective objects.

Answer (score 1):

The notification object (`[notification object]` or `notification.object`) will be the combo box that sent the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use tags? you can assign a tag 101 to one of them and a 102 to the other, then when they fire the delegate you just need to have an if clause to check the object's tag.